# API key not valid for google cloud translate

Tags: google-api, google-translate, google-translation-api

```
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');
use Google\Cloud\Translate\TranslateClient;

/** Uncomment and populate these variables in your code */
$text = 'The text to translate.';
$targetLanguage = 'hi';  // Language to translate to

$translate = new TranslateClient();
$result = $translate->translate($text, [
    'target' => $targetLanguage,
    'key'=>'&key=KEY_REAL',
]);
print("Source language: $result[source]\n");
print("Translation: $result[text]\n");


use Google\Cloud\Translate\V3\TranslationServiceClient;

$translationServiceClient = new TranslationServiceClient();

/** Uncomment and populate these variables in your code */
$text = 'This is a test. Hello, world!';
$targetLanguage = 'fr';
$projectId = 'dev-antler-288108';
$contents = $text;
$formattedParent = $translationServiceClient->locationName($projectId, 'global');

try {
    $response = $translationServiceClient->translateText(
        $contents,
        $targetLanguage,
        $formattedParent
    );
    // Display the translation for each input text provided
    foreach ($response->getTranslations() as $translation) {
        printf('Translated text: %s' . PHP_EOL, $translation->getTranslatedText());
    }
} finally {
    $translationServiceClient->close();
}
```

This is the code and when i run this i get

> Message: { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "API key not valid.
> Please pass a valid API key.", "errors": [ { "message": "API key not
> valid. Please pass a valid API key.", "domain": "global", "reason":
> "badRequest" } ], "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

is there something i am doing wrong here ???

Comment: have you considered creating a vaild api key?

Comment: yes i use a valid API key from google cloud i think i am using it at wrong place in the code.

Comment: Are you following this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/translate